# Posting Data from node.js to a coldfusion rest service

Tags: node.js, coldfusion

**Problem:** I am not able make the ColdFusion REST service to create a Datasource by sending a request from Node.js. Each time I try to post data from Node.js to my ColdFusion rest service, my argument value is empty.

**Code for posting data from Node.js**

```
var http = require('http'),
    postData = {
        name: "ab"
    },
    postData = JSON.stringify(postData),
    htOptions = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 8500,
        path: "/rest/createdsn/dsnComponent/createDataSource",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postdata)
        } 
    }

var req = http.request(htOptions);
console.log(postData)     // {"name":"ab"}
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
      console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.')
      })
      console.log('api successfully called');
    });
```

**Code for ColdFusion REST service**

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restPath="/dsnComponent">

    <cffunction name="createDataSource" access="remote"
                    returnType="any" httpMethod="POST" restpath="{strDSN}" produces="application/JSON">

        <cfargument name="strDSN" default="" type="any" restargsource="form">
        <cfdump var = #strDSN# format="html" output="D:\api.html">
          <cfset reqDSN = deserializeJSON(strDSN)>
           <cfset structDSN = structNew() >
           <cfset structDSN.driver = "MSSQLServer" >
           <cfset structDSN.name = reqDSN.name >
           <cfset structDSN.host = "localhost" >
           <cfset structDSN.port = "1433" >
           <cfset structDSN.database = reqDSN.name>
           <cfset structDSN.username = "sa" >
           <cfset structDSN.password  = "*****" >
        <cfscript>

            adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");
            adminObj = adminObj.login('***','admin');
            myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.datasource");
            myObj.setMSSQL(argumentCollection = structDSN);
            structDSN.success = myObj.verifyDSN(dsn = structDSN.name, returnMsgOnError = 'true');

        </cfscript>

        <cfset res = serializeJSON(structDSN) />
        <cfreturn structDSN>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

When I try including `headers` option in variable `htOptions` I get the following error

[image]

If I do not include headers, I get an empty string in my arguments and receives an error

`{"Message":"JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string"}`

I created a cfm page to call the rest service and it successfully created the data source in the ColdFusion administrator

**Code**

```
<cfset structDSN.name = "ab">
<cfset strDSN = serializeJSON(structDSN)>

<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8500/rest/createdsn/dsnComponent/createDataSource" method="post" port="8500" result="res">
    <cfhttpparam name="strDSN" value="#strDSN#" type="formfield" />
</cfhttp>
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which line of you node.js code is supposed to supply the argument?

Comment: your CF post example does not include a header right?

Comment: When you get the 500 error is anything showing up in api.html?

Comment: @mark no header is set. During the 500 error nothing is wrote in api.html

Comment: @dan req.write() is supposed to pass the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.JS you're using `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` header, but you're not properly encoding the data for the content type.

Also, I see you expect `strDSN` argument out of the request's form, but that's nowhere defined in it (unless I'm mistaken; I don't know much CF).
When getting form data, your request body string contains `;` delimited `argument=value` pairs, so it should look like `strDNS=URLEncodedData`.

So, either you do

```
postData = {
  name: "ab"
};
postData = querystring.stringify({strDSN: JSON.stringify(postData)}); //urlencode strDSN argument as JSON string
req.write(postData); // or req.end(postData)
```

which will yield `strDSN=%7B%22name%22%3A+%22ab%22%7D` *(all `{`, `}`, `:`, `"`, and `(space)` are URL encoded)
see https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options*

Or you use `"Content-Type": "application/json"` and

```
postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
req.write(postData); // or req.end(postData);
```

and then you probably need to `deserializeJSON()` the request body/content in your CF.

Comment: Using `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, I was not able to get any value in argument I dumped on a file. But your first suggestion in your answer help me solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem Dan but you do have a syntax error in your function CreateDataSource().

Your return var is set up like this:

```
  <cfset res = serializeJSON(structDSN) />
        <cfreturn structDSN>
```

You are returning the CF struct rather than your "res" variable.  Is that what you want?

Shouldn't it be:

```
<cfreturn serializeJSON(structDSN)>
```

Comment: Variable res should have been returned. But when the error occurs I believe it doesn't even enters inside the function to dump the receiving argument into the file api.html

Comment: What happens when you comment out that dump line?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. Will do when I get back to office tomorrow and will let you know the result

Comment: File operations can sometimes produce 500 errors with little information attached to them. That's my thinking.

Comment: Tried commenting the dump line, same error occurs. Also tried your answer but no luck yet.